# ERROR: text search configuration name "english" must be schema-qualified

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Trying to do some full text searching with postgres and when running the following command

```
UPDATE "EMAIL" SET PostText = to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', "TEXT");
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR:  text search configuration name "english" must be schema-qualified
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I've also tried

```
UPDATE "EMAIL" SET PostText = to_tsvector('english', "TEXT");
```

Edit 1:
Table EMAIL has the column "TEXT" in it.  They are both in all caps FWIW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes are for case sensitive identifiers or one's that have whitespace in them. Single quotes are for strings.

Try this:

```
UPDATE "EMAIL" SET PostText = to_tsvector('english', 'TEXT');
```

You can also remove the quotes around `"EMAIL"` for a case insensitive match on the field name as well:

```
UPDATE email SET PostText = to_tsvector('english', 'TEXT');
```

Comment: UPDATE "EMAIL" SET PostText = to_tsvector('english', TEXT');
gives me same error:

ERROR: text search configuration name "english" must be schema-qualified

Comment: deleted triggers and used your update and it worked.  Don't know why but won't a rgue it

Comment: If you deleted triggers and it worked, then perhaps the triggers' code had some error?